# Remove elements from array of objects those are less than anothers by object property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
[
{
  incoming_number: 1,
  incoming_number_fraction: 0,
  article:'a1'
},
{
  incoming_number: 2,
  incoming_number_fraction: 0,
  article:'a2'
},
{
  incoming_number: 2,
  incoming_number_fraction: 2,
  article:'a3'
},
{
  incoming_number: 3,
  incoming_number_fraction: 0,
  article:'a4'
},
{
  incoming_number: 4,
  incoming_number_fraction: 0,
  article:'a5'
},
{
  incoming_number: 4,
  incoming_number_fraction: 2,
  article:'a6'
},
{
  incoming_number: 4,
  incoming_number_fraction: 4,
  article:'a7'
},
]
```

The task is removing elements from array by this logic: if there are elements with similar *"incoming_number"*, we must save the element with max *"incoming_number_fraction"* and remove all others.
The result should be:

```
[
{
      incoming_number: 1,
      incoming_number_fraction: 0
},
{
      incoming_number: 2,
      incoming_number_fraction: 2
},
{
      incoming_number: 3,
      incoming_number_fraction: 0
},
{
      incoming_number: 4,
      incoming_number_fraction: 4
},
]
```

There are a lot of elements in array (more than 10000) and I want to do this operation in the minimum number of steps.

**EDIT**
I try something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {  
if (arr[i]['incoming_number'] === arr[i + 1]['incoming_number']) {
  let j = i + 1
  while (arr[j]['incoming_number'] === arr[j + 1]['incoming_number']) {
    j++
  }
}

arr.splice(i, j-1)
}
```

But it doesn't work...
**EDIT 2**
Adding more information about objects in array.

Comment: Have you made an attempt at solving this problem yourself? If so, what went wrong (errors, unexpected results, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to achieve this is using `reduce`, because with one iteration you will get your result and you apply your logic directly to the result array.

```js
const obj = [{
    incoming_number: 1,
    incoming_number_fraction: 0
  },
  {
    incoming_number: 2,
    incoming_number_fraction: 0
  },
  {
    incoming_number: 2,
    incoming_number_fraction: 2
  },
  {
    incoming_number: 3,
    incoming_number_fraction: 0
  },
  {
    incoming_number: 4,
    incoming_number_fraction: 0
  },
  {
    incoming_number: 4,
    incoming_number_fraction: 2
  },
  {
    incoming_number: 4,
    incoming_number_fraction: 4
  },
]

const result = obj.reduce((accum, currentValue) => {
  const index = accum.findIndex(item => currentValue.incoming_number === item.incoming_number);
  //if the index is -1 it means we didn't added that entry, so we just push it.
  if (index === -1) {
    accum.push(currentValue);
  } else {
    //this means that we have an entry with that incoming number, then we compare the incoming_number_fraction
    if (currentValue.incoming_number_fraction > accum[index].incoming_number_fraction) {
      accum[index] = currentValue;
    }
  }
  return accum;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, your variant works with old array example and with updated.

Answer (score 1):

Using findIndex or grep to find the selected number in a big array is bad for performance.
so using the number as a property will be the fastest way to find the object and change `incoming_number_fraction`.

Using grep, findindex may result in a samller code but not better performance and in your case you need performance more then smaller code.

have a look at my example and let me know.

```js
var arr=[
{
  incoming_number: 1,
  incoming_number_fraction: 0,
  article:'a1'
},
{
  incoming_number: 2,
  incoming_number_fraction: 0,
  article:'a2'
},
{
  incoming_number: 2,
  incoming_number_fraction: 2,
  article:'a3'
},
{
  incoming_number: 3,
  incoming_number_fraction: 0,
  article:'a4'
},
{
  incoming_number: 4,
  incoming_number_fraction: 0,
  article:'a5'
},
{
  incoming_number: 4,
  incoming_number_fraction: 2,
  article:'a6'
},
{
  incoming_number: 4,
  incoming_number_fraction: 4,
  article:'a7'
},
]

var finalResult = [];
var result = {};
var includedNumbers = []
arr.forEach(function(item){
var number = item.incoming_number;
if (!result[item.incoming_number]){ // with Index, is the fastest way 
     result[number] = item;
     includedNumbers.push(number);
  }else {
     if (result[number].incoming_number_fraction< item.incoming_number_fraction ){
         result[number] = item;
     }
   
  }
});

// now lets clean the result 
includedNumbers.forEach(function(item){
  finalResult.push(result[item])
});

console.log(finalResult)
```

Comment: It's a my mistake, that I use in example simple object. And if you try again run your code with updated array, it doesn't work as needed. I understand how yout code wotks, it doesn't delete, it replace elements :(

Comment: Ok i understand what you mean now. you need the whole object with max incoming_number_fraction not just incoming_number_fraction. ok i fixed it now it should work like you needed it to work. try it and let me know

Comment: This is strange. The result in snippet is right, and in my project it works too, but in jsfiddle - it doesn't work correctly. If you are interested in: https://jsfiddle.net/dpsjLbu2/2/

Comment: in fiddler you have `var number = item.incoming_number` instead of `incoming_number_fraction`